# How do I convert a slice object to a string that can go in brackets?

Tags: python, slice

I have a class in which I store a `slice` object because the actual slicing happens in a later part of the application. In this function's `__repr__`, however, I want to print something that looks like what you would write yourself.

```
class DelaySlice(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, slice):
        self.obj = obj
        self.slice = slice
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s[%s]" % (self.obj, self.slice)

class OtherObject(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "other_object_instance"
    def __getitem__(self, slice):
        return DelaySlice(self, slice)
```

With this, `print(OtherObject()[:2]` prints `other_object_instance[slice(None, 2, None)]`. I would like it to print `other_object_instance[:2]`.

How should I change `DelaySlice.__repr__` to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet that does this for the obvious cases.

```
def __repr__(self):
    sl_start = "" if self.slice.start is None else str(self.slice.start)
    sl_stop = "" if self.slice.stop is None else str(self.slice.stop)
    if self.slice.step is None:
        sl_str = "%s:%s" % (sl_start, sl_stop)
    else:
        sl_str = "%s:%s:%s" % (sl_start, sl_stop, self.slice.step)
    return "%s[%s]" % (self.obj, sl_str)
```

If you use this as `DelaySlice.__repr__` it will print as expected

```
>>> OtherObject()[:2]
other_object_instance[:2]
>>> OtherObject()[1:2]
other_object_instance[1:2]
>>> OtherObject()[1:]
other_object_instance[1:]
>>> OtherObject()[1::4]
other_object_instance[1::4]
```